# neo4j / cypher : delete double linked list in one request

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using Neo4j, i have done an implementation of a newsfeeds for each users.
I am using a double linked list with two kind of relation "next_activity" / "prev_activity".
On each activity node i can have others relations as "LIKE".
When a delete an user in my system i would like to delete all the news feeds.
So i have to iterate each activity, delete it (and all relations as LIKE) and be able to go to the next using the relation "next_activity".

Does it possible using Cypher in one request (i mean using the *..100 option).

Thank you!

---

I have tried (version 1.8.2) :

```
    start user=node:id(id="...") match  path=user-[r:NEXT|PREV|LIKES*]->activity
    with relationships(path) as act_r, nodes(path) as act_n
    foreach(r in act_r : delete r)
    with act_n
    foreach(n in act_n : delete n);
```

But i have 'TransactionFailureException"

I am going to test on 1.9.2 RC2

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should work:

```
start user=node... // lookup user in index
match p=user-[:NEXT*]-activity // find all activities nodes in the linked list
with nodes(p) as activities // this also includes the user
foreach activity in activities: 
  match activity-[r?]-() // get all relationships coming off of each activity
  delete activities, r; // delete all for each activity
```

Update: New idea. I'll leave the other idea there for posterity. This should work because it should match each path until the end, and we'll just use the endpoint to delete the :LIKE relationships (or any relationship) going off of those.

```
start user=node... // lookup user in index
match p=user-[:NEXT*]-activity, activity-[r?]-()
delete user, activity, r;
```

I built a graph and tested it, so I think it should be a general solution.

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=nnj5h8

Comment: Thanks, that's a good clue, but for now it returns :
CyperTypeException : Expected 'activities' to be a Node but i was a Collection 

i think i have to use foreach or something like that on activies collection? (i am using 1.8.2 version)

Comment: sorry, yeah. you would need to do foreach for this.

Comment: This may or may not work in 1.8.2, I don't have time to test it until later tonight...

Comment: Ok, i try it on 1.9.2 now, i will get you in touch.

Comment: Unfortunately We can't use MATCH in FOREACH, also in 1.9.RC2

Comment: Bleh... need to figure out a different way then.